# iOS Swift Notifications action background color

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, action, background-color

[image: Notification Action Buttons]

After some search i couldn't find information on how to change notification button background colors. Is this possible to do with Swift in iOS?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you can do is to set it to red color. You can achieve it if you set `actionButton.destructive` equal to `true`